# Permutations of a list without repeating the first number

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to create a list of sets of 3 items containing all combinations of the items from list where the first number in each set is not repeated.

**For example:**
Set is A,B,C
**Results:**
ABC
BCA
CAB

I have tried using itertools import permutations, but this will give me all possible permutations including one's where the first (left hand) item repeats.
For example:
ABC
ACB

I have used the below code:

```
from itertools import permutations    
a = ["A123", "A456","A789"]
p = permutations(a)  
  
for j in list(p):
    print(j)
```

Comment: It might be easiest to use permutations anyway, and edit the results afterwards to remove the unwanted items.

Comment: So you literally want to rotate the list once per element?

Comment: If you dont want the first element to repeat, you also dont want the first and second to repeat? So in other words, you dont really want permutations?

Answer (score 2):

It's not crystal clear what you're trying to accomplish here, but if you literally want one output per `n` items in your input list, you can just rotate.

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(["A123", "A456","A789"])
output = []
for x in range(len(d)):
    output.append(list(d.copy()))
    d.rotate()
    
for x in output:
    print(x)
```

Output

```
['A123', 'A456', 'A789']
['A789', 'A123', 'A456']
['A456', 'A789', 'A123']
```

Edit:

If you need only 3 elements per result:

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(["A123", "A456","A789",'A666','A777'])
output = []
for x in range(len(d)):
    output.append(list(d.copy())[:3])
    d.rotate()
    
for x in output:
    print(x)
```

Output

```
['A123', 'A456', 'A789']
['A777', 'A123', 'A456']
['A666', 'A777', 'A123']
['A789', 'A666', 'A777']
['A456', 'A789', 'A666']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the rotation like this too:

```
a = ["A123", "A456","A789"]
for i in range(len(a)): print (a[i+1:]+a[:i+1])
```

This will result in:

```
['A456', 'A789', 'A123']
['A789', 'A123', 'A456']
['A123', 'A456', 'A789']
```

This will rotate as many elements as you want. Here's another example:

```
a = ["A12", "A34","A56","A78","A90"]
for i in range(len(a)): print (a[i+1:]+a[:i+1])
```

Its just moving the position of the `i`th element to the next position while ensuring all elements of the list are pulled together in the end.

```
['A34', 'A56', 'A78', 'A90', 'A12']
['A56', 'A78', 'A90', 'A12', 'A34']
['A78', 'A90', 'A12', 'A34', 'A56']
['A90', 'A12', 'A34', 'A56', 'A78']
['A12', 'A34', 'A56', 'A78', 'A90']
```

Comment: instead of printing the list, you can decided to store it into a list and take only what you want. Looks like you want only 3 items. You can pull 3 each time. Make sure you have enough to pull on the last iteration.